# How to find columns/Features for which there are at least X percentage of rows with Identical Values? [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let us say I have an extremely large dataset with 'N' rows and 'M' features. I also have two inputs.

1. 'm' : defines the number of features to check(m

   'support' = Identical Rows/ Total rows for the 'm' subset of features. This is basically the **minimum** percentage of identical rows considering an 'm' number of features

I need to return the groups of features for which the 'support' value is greater than a predefined value.

For Example, let us take this dataset:

```py
d = {
     'A': [100, 200, 200, 400,400], 'B': [1,2,2,4,5],
     'C':['2018-11-19','2018-11-19','2018-12-19','2018-11-19','2018-11-19']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


     A      B       C

0   100     1   2018-11-19

1   200     2   2018-11-19

2   200     2   2018-12-19

3   400     4   2018-11-19

4   400     5   2018-11-19
```

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sT1o.png)

In the above example if let us say that

'm' = 2

'support' = 0.4

Then the function should return both ['A','B] and ['A','C'] as both these features when considered together have at least 2 identical rows out of a total of 5 rows (>= 0.4).

I realize that a naive solution would be to to compare all combinations of 'm' features out of 'M' and check the percentage of identical rows. However this will get incredibly complex after the magnitude of features crosses double digits, especially with thousands of rows. What would be an optimized code to tackling this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Comment: Please keep in mind that tags are about the *content* of the question, *not* its context.

Comment: Yep, will do! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think this is highly related to market basket analysis, specifically, the [a-priori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) could be worth investigating